# How to concatenate a backslash before a variable containing a namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to append a backslash at the beginning of a string to use it as a namespace.

```
$class = get_class($model);
$nodes = "\\$class"::defaultOrder()->get();
```

But I get this error:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::defaultOrder()

I just can't find the correct syntax.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: @tttony It won't work as I need a backslash at the start: `\App\Models\Post`

Comment: Could you post your class where defaultOrder id defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, you will have to surround the variable expression in curly braces as mentioned in the [`docs`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in the complex expressions' section. So it will be like below:

```
<?php

$nodes = "\\{$class}"::defaultOrder()->get();
```

[**Live Sample Demo**](https://3v4l.org/0V8tZ)